# Remote VNC - can't browse the web on the remote machine

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm connecting to my remote machine via RealVNC. I'm using Win10 on both pcs. I port-forwarded the right port on my home router (5800) and connecting works great.

The problem is: I can't connect to ANY pc on the remote lan via the viewer. I'll explain this better: 
connecting to the remote machine with the VNC viewer works, I can see the desktop and do whatever I like, but when opening Chrome or Firefox on the remote machine and trying to navigate to www.google.com, to google's ip directly or even to my home router page (192.168.1.1 - the one where I did the port forwarding), won't work.

Pinging the router works. Navigating to the webserver interface doesn't. Pinging websites works. Navigating via http doesn't.

I tried cleaning arp cache, dns cache flushing, etc.. it seems that as soon as I log out RealVNC the http connections come back to life. I disabled any firewall (except Windows' one).

Any hint on how to debug this?

Edit: I'm also adding the output of a tracert as requested

```
C:\Users\Paul>tracert www.google.com

traceroute to www.google.com [216.58.210.196]
30 hops max, 40 byte packets:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  modem.homenet.myisp.com [192.168.1.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timeout.
```

and a `telnet google.com 80` request

```
GET / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1555
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 10:04:35 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
               <html lang=en>
                               <meta charset=utf-8>
                                                     <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
                                                          <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
                     <style>
                                *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
                                              </style>
                                                        <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
                                               <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
           <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: What does a tracert show?

Comment: @MrStatic edited and added the output. Thanks for helping.

Comment: So you are routing properly. What about telnet google.com 80

Comment: @MrStatic Added. There's indeed something wrong with http. The same remote pc used to work great yesterday before I activated realVNC and left it for the night.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is anything to do with RealVNC, perhaps you should remove that from the question as it it seems irrelevant. I'm assuming you have exactly the same problem if you tried to browse when you were physically in front of the machine?